# data from www.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I would like to get data from [www.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor](http://www.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor%20page) page, Is there any official or unofficial api which will allow to get data (campaign name, buying type, total daily budget , .... ).

I already have tried to scrap that page, but it seems that it is not so easy(html isn't well structured), and I didn't find api which will allow to get the data, that's why I would like to get help from you.

Thanks .

[image]

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong with my question that I can as good questions in future,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Ads API. You can find the documentation for it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-api . And scraping is not a good idea because it is not allowed by Facebook

Comment: Thank you @WizKid for help, I am not going to do it constantly, I need to get data only one time. I failed to find a api call which will return that info, could you please help me with that?

Comment: If you are just going to do it once just click the button next to the + button up to the left. And select Export All

Comment: Thank you very much for help I missed that button,

Comment: but now requirements have changed and if possible I would  like to get data from service ,  in that case I need to get data using api, could you please help me with that  , I am having hard time understanding how FB ads api work?

Comment: To list all campaigns for an ad account id you use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adcampaign/v2.2#by_account